# mongoose networking library link issue VS19 c++ project

Tags: c++, mongoose, server, linker

I cannot get work mongoose, visual studio have some LINK problems.
Just trying to run an example from https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/http-server/main.c

What I did:

1. create c++ project
2. include mongoose.c and mongoose.h, then create main.cpp
3. Copy code in here
4. RUN => linker errors for x64
5. so I did new blain c++ project for building library
6. include mongoose.c and mongoose.h
7. build .lib for x64
8. give a path for first project => still LINK problems (now different)

All erors are similar:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_bind referenced in function     mg_open_listener    
    mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\mongoose.obj  1

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_casecmp referenced in function main       mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1   

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_http_listen referenced in function main   mongooseWebServer       E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_http_serve_dir referenced in     function "void __cdecl cb(struct mg_connection *,int,void *,void *)" (?    cb@@YAXPEAUmg_connection@@HPEAX1@Z)   mongooseWebServer       E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1   

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_log referenced in function main       mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_log_prefix referenced in function     main    mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_log_set referenced in function main       mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1   

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol mg_mgr_poll referenced in function 
    main    mongooseWebServer   E:\JOB\StitchingProject\mongooseWebServer\main.obj  1
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that mongoose need also their .exe program running in backgroud, similar to the apache. EXE itself is unsecured and antivirus must be turned off...

To be able to compile with their libraries, this EXE must running.